# Exposing the Sublists like Enumeration

Tags: wpf, list

I have a List of type List> itemListList which contains ObservableCollection in my custom control.

I have exposed these list as Static in my Custom control.

Below is the Code to illustrate my scenario :

```
public static List<ObservableCollection<IItem>> itemListList;

    // 3 Panel Lists of type ObservableCollection

    public static ObservableCollection<IItem> iItemsList0;
    public static ObservableCollection<IItem> iItemsList1;
    public static ObservableCollection<IItem> iItemsList2;
```

In the Client side , these items would be added to these lists :

```
            UI.itemListList = new List<ObservableCollection<IItem>>();

            // Adding Items to the List

        /*First Collection */

            UI.iItemsList0 = new ObservableCollection<IItem>();

            UI.iItemsList0.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList0.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList0.Add(new UC());


            /*Second Collections */
            UI.iItemsList1 = new ObservableCollection<IItem>();

            UI.iItemsList1.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList1.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList1.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList1.Add(new UC());

            /*Third Collection */
            UI.iItemsList2 = new ObservableCollection<IItem>();

            UI.iItemsList2.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList2.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList2.Add(new UC());
            UI.iItemsList2.Add(new UC());
```

On the Control Side ,

I would add these sub lists to the List> type.

```
    UI.itemListList.Add(iItemsList0);
    UI.itemListList.Add(iItemsList1);
    UI.itemListList.Add(iItemsList2);
```

This works fine . Items get added to the list but if u are a user you would not know yourself which are the Sublists being exposed .
The way i would like to modify this code is I can tell the User the MainList  itemListList being exposed but then 
from there on he should be able to access the sublists .

Something like Enumeration .is my question clear .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary` of collections, with the key being an enumeration, and the value being the observable collection:

```
public enum ListType
{
    MyFirstList,
    MySecondList
}

public static Dictionary<ListType, ObservableCollection<IItem>> Lists;

// Instantiate and populate Lists


// Get an observable collection by key
var observableCollection = UI.Lists[ListType.MyFirstList];
```

It doesn't seem a particularly nice design though, so you might want to rethink the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks . I will look into the design again . If you find any mistakes with the design ,  Plz do share.

Comment: There are a few things I would suggest, firstly you might consider using MVVM if you are building a WPF app, and with that I would use an MVVM framework. Secondly, if you are wishing to share collections of items between view models/views, then I wouldn't do this at the UI level. I would instead have this is a service that is injected into each view model, with methods that return each type of list that you need to reuse.

Comment: Also, if you found the answer useful, don't forget to accept it